# Liquidity Pool Question

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I did my research on liquidity pools and I observed you need a deployed token in order to create a pool.

My question is,

How do I write the code to add a percentage of a transaction to the liquidity pool before the contract is deployed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit these trading fees on Uniswap V2 style AMM AFAIK. The factory contract is deploying a pair contract that is hard-coded in the factory.